# pyinstaller executable has errors but is completely fine when opening .py file on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

***I'm trying to make an executable file for a project so my friends don't need to install python, using pyinstaller***

**When using pyinstaller with "-w"**
The executable shows an Attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    display = calendar_object.make_calendar()
AttributeError: 'Calendar' object has no attribute 'make_calendar'
```

but when I open main.py in the terminal it is completely fine.

**When using pyinstaller without "-w"**
It opens and closes immediately, and yes I have a while loop and an input inside so I'm guessing there's again, something wrong with my file

***Temporary Solution:***
Inserting all the separate files into one file.

Code Sample:
[main.py](https://pastebin.com/xYyMANhD)
[calendar.py](https://pastebin.com/h6p9N6ct)

Comment: Without your code and the actual exception it is very hard to help you diagnose the issue. Please add the details of the exception raised and the (relevant part of the) code

Comment: start by creating a simple program that prints "Hello World" and requests an input (so it doesn't close automatically). Then compile this 2 line program into an exe. this way you can see if your problem comes from something wrong using pyinstaller or from your code.

Comment: @Jonathan I added pastebin samples of my code, if it helps I use Windows 11

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried it and had no problem at all. Tried adding my code slowly and figured out that using the make_calendar() is the part that makes the executable immediately close or raise the attribute error.

Comment: dont post links to code. post your code in the question properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a name for your class that is mimicking the python internal calendar class.

Rename your class and you should be fine